# About fluid flow inside channels on speed and pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

My question was what is the effect of curvature channel (half circle), wavy Channel, parallel channel and triangular channel on speed and pressure inside the channel?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @zaid mdo: Can you give more information in the question?

Comment: Dear sir thanks for your reply I just have channels with dimensions 1 m the high and 4 m the length and 1 m width . So I have fluid flow inside the three kinds of channels the mentioned up I have do the simulation for it with small speed so I want to know the effects of this channels on speed and pressure